# $this->auth->login() always return false

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.6.7
**In AppController.php**

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'email', //Default is 'username' in the userModel
                        'password' => 'password'  //Default is 'password' in the userModel
                    ),
                    'userModel' => 'Admin',
                    'passwordHasher' => array(
                        'className' => 'Simple',
                        'hashType' => 'sha256'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => 'admins',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'deshboard'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => "You can't acces that page",
            'authorize' => 'Controller'
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        //parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('index');
    }
```

**In AdminsController.php**

```
<?php

    class AdminsController extends AppController {

        var $layout = 'admin';
      public function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter();
           $this->Auth->allow('create');
        }
        function login() {

            $this->loadModel('Admin');
            $this->layout = "admin-login";
            // if already logged in check this step
            if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
                return $this->Auth->loginRedirect; //(array('action' => 'deshboard'));
            }
            // after submit login form check this step
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                    echo 'ok<br/>';
                    echo 'last query: '.$this->Admin->getLastQuery();
                exit;
                    return $this->Auth->loginRedirect;
                } else {
                     echo 'Not ok<br/>';
                     echo 'last query: '.$this->Admin->getLastQuery();
                exit;
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username/password combination OR you are blocked, try again');
                    return $this->Auth->logoutRedirect;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**Model/admin.php**

```
<?php


    App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
    class Admin extends AppModel {

        var $name = "admin";
        var $belongsTo = array('Role');
        public $validate = array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'required' => true,
                'message' => 'Email already exist'
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '6'),
                'message' => 'password must be minimum 6 characters long'
            )
        );

        function hashPassword() {
         if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
                $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher(array('hashType' => 'sha256'));
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                    $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
                );
            }
        }

        function beforeSave($options = array()) {
            $this->hashPassword();
            return true;
        }

    }

    ?>
```

**In View/admin/login.ctp**

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="loginContainer">
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('Admin', array(
            'inputDefaults' => array(
                'label' => false,
                'div' => false
            ),
            'class' => 'form-horizontal',
            'role' => 'form',
            'id'=>'loginForm',
            'url' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'),
        ));
        ?>
            <div class="form-row row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <label class="form-label span12" for="username">
                            Email:
                            <span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-user-3 right gray marginR10"></span>
                        </label>
                        <?php
                        echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
                            'class' => 'span12',
                            'id' => 'username',
                            'type' => 'text',
                        ));
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <label class="form-label span12" for="password">
                            Password:
                            <span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-locked right gray marginR10"></span>
                            <span class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span>
                        </label>
                        <?php
                        echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
                            'class' => 'span12',
                            'id' => 'password',
                            'type' => 'password',
                        ));
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row row-fluid">                       
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <div class="span12 controls">
                                <?php
                                echo $this->Form->button(
                                        'Login', array('class' => 'btn marginR10', 'type' => 'submit')
                                );
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>

</div><!-- End .container-fluid -->
```

**Problem is** $this->auth->login()  always return false.

```
I checked the last query after $this->auth->login() called. The query is:
last query: SELECT `Admin`.`id`, `Admin`.`role_id`, `Admin`.`name`, `Admin`.`email`, `Admin`.`password`, `Admin`.`mobile`, `Admin`.`area`, `Admin`.`status`, `Admin`.`comment`, `Admin`.`created`, `Role`.`id`, `Role`.`name`, `Role`.`created`, `Role`.`modified` FROM `amrajegeachi`.`admins` AS `Admin` LEFT JOIN `amrajegeachi`.`roles` AS `Role` ON (`Admin`.`role_id` = `Role`.`id`) WHERE `Admin`.`email` = 'sattar.kuet@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
```

In the Where clause the password is missing. I would like to know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: what is the cake version ?

Comment: my current cakephp version is 2.6.7

Comment: How did you resolve his problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set variable in AppController BeforeFilter action,

```
$this->set('isLoggedIn',$this->Auth->loggedIn());
```

Check in other controller with the same variable, It won't make problem.